# Test media queries in browser

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

Knows somebody good websites, where i can test my website on diffrent mobile viewports ?

Chrome "developer tools" dont bring me what im looking for!

Is there something like http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ where i can uploud my files?

and not have to push the files first on my server?

```
<a>Greetings from Bavaria and sorry for my englisch!</a>
```

Hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://testsize.com/ You can enter custom width and height if you want.

If you don't have a web host you can upload your html pages here. http://pastehtml.com/

Answer (score 0):

Most of css width and height functions could be successfully tested through manually changing the browser width or height. By that I mean holding the edge of the browser window when it isn't maximized and move it to the right, left, up or down.